# ESP32 PWM duty cycle measurement from input

Tags: microcontroller, esp32, code

I am trying to measure the duty cycle interval (from falling to rising edge) in microseconds of an incoming PWM signal of 20 KHz.

I made a test PWM signal on a GPIO pin (50% duty) and connected it to input pin.

Up to 80 microseconds it is all good and stable, but if I raise the PWM frequency, below 80 µs the readings start to get unstable and unusable, the value starts jumping around and doesn't show a "real" value. Why so?

```
static void IRAM_ATTR rising_handler(void* arg) {
uint32_t gpio_num = (uint32_t)arg;
xQueueSendFromISR(rising_evt_queue, &gpio_num, NULL);
}

static void rising_task(void* arg) {
uint32_t io_num;
for (;;) {
    if (xQueueReceive(rising_evt_queue, &io_num, portMAX_DELAY)) {
        // ESP_LOGI(INTERUPT_TAG, "GPIO_INTR_NEGEDGE!!!");
        if (gpio_get_level(io_num)) {
            // ESP_LOGI(INTERUPT_TAG, "True!!!");
            pwm_value = esp_timer_get_time() - prev_time;
        }
        if (!gpio_get_level(io_num)) {
            // ESP_LOGI(INTERUPT_TAG, "False!!!");
            prev_time = esp_timer_get_time();
        }
    }
  }
}

void app_main(void) {
initPeriodicTimer(100000);
attachInterupt(4, rising_task, rising_handler, GPIO_INTR_ANYEDGE, true);

while (1) {
    // if (flag) {
    printf("%lu\n", pwm_value);
    // flag = false;
    // }
    vTaskDelay(50 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
  }
}

void attachInterupt(uint8_t gpio, voidFuncPtrArg userTask, voidFuncPtrArg isr_handler, uint8_t, triggerEdge, bool installISR) {
gpio_config_t io_conf;
// interrupt of rising edge
io_conf.intr_type = triggerEdge;
// bit mask of the pins, use GPIO4/5 here
io_conf.pin_bit_mask = (1ULL << gpio);
// set as input mode
io_conf.mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
// enable pull-up mode
io_conf.pull_up_en = 1;
gpio_config(&io_conf);
if (installISR) {
    // install gpio isr service
    gpio_install_isr_service(ESP_INTR_FLAG_DEFAULT);
}
rising_evt_queue = xQueueCreate(10, sizeof(uint32_t));
xTaskCreate(rising_task, "gpio_task_example", 2048, NULL, 10, NULL);
// hook isr handler for specific gpio pin
gpio_isr_handler_add(gpio, isr_handler, (void*)gpio);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the actual readings you get above 20kHz?

Comment: Ive printed it on terminal, is just jumps around from 4 uS to 15 uS, and sometimes randomly up to 4000uS

Comment: My first idea is that your program simply isn't fast enough, but 4000us is strange for aliasing.

Comment: But if that was the problem, it would be worse for very small or very large duty cycles. You could test that.

Comment: The code i posted basically is all my program, except includes and 1 output pin trigering in x interval. With large dudtycycles it works with no probem, it starts to get glitchy when off period is lower than 80uS

Answer (score 3):

There will be a delay between the input changing state and your interrupt routine getting control. I haven't measured this, but it wouldn't be surprising if this was a few tens of microseconds. Also, you are potentially reading the pin state three times for each transition. Once by the fact that the interrupt fires, and another one or two times by your gpio_get_level calls.  These functions do add extra processing time, and what happens if the pin state changes back while the CPU is still processing your interrupt handler?

Take a look at the Remote Control Peripheral (RMT.) To quote the ESP32 technical reference manual:

> A receiver will inspect its input signal, optionally filtering it, and will place the lengths of time the signal is active and inactive in the RAM block.

Sounds ideal for your application.